# JS XHR Upload Error When Changing Browser Tab in Firefox

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, firefox, upload, xmlhttprequest

I'm encountering an annoying issue on a website I'm developing. Essentially, I need to perform a direct upload via the client to a presigned S3 (Scaleway) URL using XMLHttpRequest. The process is relatively straightforward: I send the file via a PUT request to the URL, receive progress updates from the event, update the status bar, and submit the form to save the data.

The problem arises when I try to switch browser tabs; at that point, I receive various different errors, and sometimes the error doesn't occur at all. Currently, I'm experiencing this issue on Firefox desktop for macOS (v117.0.1), but it doesn't seem to be a problem on Windows. Other browsers like Chrome and Edge do not appear to have this issue.

The errors I encounter vary:

- CORS_FAILED
- NS_ERROR_NET_INTERRUPT

In the console, I always see: Blocked cross-origin request.

This is the function:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("PUT", presignedUrl, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", file.type);

    const filename = file.name.replace(/[.\s+]/g, "_");

    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", (event) => {
        if (event.lengthComputable) {
            const percent = Math.round((event.loaded / event.total) * 100);
            const progressBar = $(`#progress-${filename}`);

            progressBar.css("width", percent + "%").text(`${percent} %`);
        }
    });

    xhr.onload = () => {
        if (xhr.status === 200 || xhr.status === 204) {
            resolve();
        } else {
            console.error("Errore nella richiesta. Status code:", xhr.status);
            reject(new Error("Errore durante il caricamento del file " + file.name));
        }
    };

    xhr.onerror = () => {
        console.log("error");
        reject(new Error("Errore durante il caricamento del file " + file.name));
    };

    xhr.send(file);
});
```

The CORS rules in the bucket have already been set:

```
 "CORSRules": [
   {
     "AllowedOrigins": ["*"],
     "AllowedHeaders": ["*"],
     "AllowedMethods": ["GET", "HEAD", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"],
     "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000,
     "ExposeHeaders": ["Etag"]
   }
 ]
```

- I tried to make a POST request, but the result is the same.
- I tried also Axios, but the result is the same.